# How to receive keywords from auto complete suggestions without a comma added to the end in jQuery UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I want to include the functionality of `autocomplete` when a user types something in a `content editable` div. He should always get suggestions every time he types a new word to construct sentence. So I found `jquery UI` that serves my need.

Here is the jsfiddle that shows it works http://jsfiddle.net/8ky5um7n/

Now the problem here is every time the user gets an `autocomplete` suggestion and selects one, the value is added to the text but is succeeded by a `comma`. So basically the text ends up looking like a comma separated values.

Now what I want to do is remove the `comma` that is added to every selection from the `auto complete` list such that it looks like a sentence rather than a comma separated list.

So after looking into the code, I found this piece of code which adds `comma` to the end of the selected word.

```
select: function (event, ui) {

                var value = $(this).html();
                var terms = split(value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                $(this).html(terms+", ");
                placeCaretAtEnd(this);

            return false;
        }
```

As you can see, this piece of code `$(this).html(terms+", ");` adds a `comma` in the end. So on modifying it to this

```
$(this).html(terms);  // I want just the term. So when user receives it, he presses space and next autocomplete suggestion is expected
```

It gives back the result without a `comma` but then on, it doesn't suggest anymore for next words in the sentence.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your fiddle does not appear to work, I see 2 errors in console. *TypeError: $(...).bind(...).autocomplete is not a function _display:102:8* and *TypeError: $.ui is undefined 5 _display:97:13*

Comment: What do you want o use as your delimiter? I am guessing that since you want to build a sentence, you want to use a space `" "`. Currently, your code is using a comma `","` so that it can more easily create an Array and then manipulate the array.

Comment: In doing some testing, when you select the first item, and then start to type the second word, something is removing the space between the two words causing it to try and filter incorrectly. Testing further.

Answer (score 1):

In your split function you can set the seperator, for example if you want to change into semicolon ; you can write:

```
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /;\s*/ );
}
```

Then you would change the html insertion to:

```
$(this).html(terms.join(" ") + "; ");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jzn4Lvek/

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `&nbsp;` as you delimiter instead of `,`. For example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/0omdux5h/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];


  function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined" &&
      typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
      var range = document.createRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(el);
      range.collapse(false);
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
      var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
      textRange.moveToElementText(el);
      textRange.collapse(false);
      textRange.select();
    }
  }


  function split(val) {
    return val.split("&nbsp;");
  }

  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }

  $("#tags")
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
      if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    })
    .autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function(request, response) {
        var that = $("#tags");
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
          availableTags, extractLast(that.html())));
      },
      focus: function() {
        return false;
      },
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split($(this).html());
        terms.pop();
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        var str = terms.join(" ");
        $(this).html(str + "&nbsp;");
        placeCaretAtEnd(this);
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```

This gets rendered in HTML as a [Non-Breaking Space](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) and works better with your cursor function. I found that no matter what, the entry of new text would cause the space to drop. Functionally, this should not be an issue. If you're saving the data someplace, I would run it through a replacement function and convert them back to spaces as they are a different character.

```
function nbsp2Space(val){
  return val.replace("&nbsp;", " ");
}
```

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't seem to work. I do not get any suggestions when I type a letter.

Comment: Ok when I copied your code and pasted in a new fiddle, it gave suggestion for the first word but didn't give for the next word.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. @Peter's solution was close. So I had to change at two places. First the `split` function had to be changed to

```
function split( val ) {
      return val.split( / \s*/ );  //notice the (space) that I provided
    }
```

Second I had to change the `html` insertion to this

```
$(this).html(terms.join(" ") + "");
```

Now the user types a letter, gets suggestions, selects it, hits space, types second letter, gets suggestion and so on.